# Response status code [200] is not a redirect status code. Failed asserting that false is true

Tags: unit-testing, testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-testing

this is my code laravel unit testing for login

```
public function testClientSucceslogin()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'password' => 'secret',
        'status' => User::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        'type' => User::TYPE_CLIENT
    ]);
    $clientProfile = ClientProfile::where('client_id', $user->client_id)->first();
    $client_alias = Client::where('id', $user->client_id)->first();

    $this->get(route('login', [$user->email, $user->password]))
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertRedirect('dashboard', [$client_alias->alias, $clientProfile->id])
        ->assertTrue(true);


}
```

and I got this error

```
Response status code [200] is not a redirect status code. Failed asserting that false is true.
```

and i changed status code to 302 but i got this error

```
enter code heExpected status code 302 but received 200.
```

Failed asserting that false is true.

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: `->assertResponseStatus($code);` if you are trying to assert the response status code given use that

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::assertResponseStatus()
@iamcaleberic

Comment: What is unclear? You start by expecting 200 and a redirect. This doesn't make sense, since 200 means success, not redirect. Then you expect 302 and redirect. That makes sense, but the test fails because what you actually receive is 200, not 302. So, either the code is incorrect because it should redirect, but doesn't, or the test is incorrect, because it expects a redirect and a code 302 although the code is supposed to return a 200.

Comment: @flower i think there might be something wrong with your code.

Comment: I suspect the page is doing a redirect through Javascript or an HTML meta tag. If that's the case, the redirect is handled by the browser, not through the protocol layer.

Answer (score 0):

`assertRedirect()` first tests your status code. If you don't follow [the rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30), you might just want to check if a [`Location` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) is present in the response.

In 5.8+, you can do it via `assertLocation()`:

```php
$this->get(route('login', [$user->email, $user->password]))
     ->assertStatus(200)
     ->assertLocation('your-location')
     ->assertTrue(true);
```

In 5.4, you have do use `PHPUnit::assertEquals()`

```php
$response = $this->get(route('login', [$user->email, $user->password]));
$response->assertStatus(200)
     ->assertTrue(true);
PHPUnit::assertEquals(app('url')->to($uri), $response->headers->get('Location'));
```